# Pages section (only) not loading after publishing large number of pages

Tags: wp-admin, errors, performance

I'm having some issues with my first wordpress installation that's really throwing me for a loop. First some background info on the situation.

I've been working on converting an HTML site into wordpress. Since the site was quite large (around 8000 pages) I used a plugin to import the HTML files. While doing so I found that I had to import them as drafts otherwise the import would fail. I started publishing groups of pages so that I could properly link from pages when i was fixing up the layouts and such. However when I get to around 3000 pages published the Pages section of wordpress no longer loads. I can access anything else in wordpress (Posts/Appearance/etc.) but clicking on any of the Pages section will cause Chrome to spit out:

```
"Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."
```

I did some looking online and in the codex and found a few suggestions for fixes but nothing seems to be working. I've tried disabling/removing all plugins, removing all themes other than the default twentyten, deleting my wp_config file to set up a new install and copying the posts and postmeta to the new database in phpmyadmin, completely overwriting all wordpress files with a freshly downloaded copy, with and without a cache plugin, with pretty and ugly permalinks, and probably a few other small things. I've also tried accessing it from an entirely different location to make sure it wasn't an issue with my local connection. I had WP-DBManager plugin installed and if I revert to an older backup (less pages published) everything will work properly again.

As stated it's my first wordpress site so I'm not familiar with all of it yet but I've not had any issues i haven't been able to solve easily up to this point. I'm also not the very familiar with SQL databases but I understand the basics of that fairly well. To me it seems like it might be a problem with the database but I've been unable to figure out how to approach it from here. I feel like i'm going around in circles a bit at this point.
Not sure if this is important to this issue or not, but I did increase the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in /wp-includes/default-constants.php to 64M initially to account for the increased database size prior to the problem and have tried it with 128M to see if that would solve the problem but does not.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated as I'm stuck at a standstill.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is your permalink structure ( `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` )?

Comment: I had it set on Day and Name, but i've also tried with the default permalink structure.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're either running into issues with verbose rewrite rules (which, if you've reverted to default permalink structure and still have the problem, isn't the problem), or else you're just running into server resource limits. Have you tried using W3 Total Cache or another caching Plugin, to see if anything improves?

Comment: I Had WP Super Cache installed but realize now I hadn't preloaded it yet.  I have it currently running a preload and will report back when that is done.  I understand that a cache plugin will make a big difference for visitors but would it have as large of an impact on the back-end (where i'm experiencing the problem) too?

Comment: Still waiting for it to finish preloading the pages into the cache, but with it 1/3 of the way done, it still gives me the error when trying to access the pages section of the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you run into the limit of the PHP configuration. I guess you run into the `max_execution_time` which is usually 30 seconds.
Also you can overrun the `memory_limit` in PHP, server config as well.

You should take a look at the error logs output, they should tell you more on the problem. (ask your service provider for access)

Also, for caching: `add define('WP_CACHE',true);` to the begining of wp_config.php
and if your server supports APC, use the [APC Object Cache Backend plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/apc/).